# Script to find all colored cells in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a script that will type a value into every colored cell in a given range
I am very new to all of this so forgive my ignorance.
From the reading I've done I've come up with this

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim colors As Range, found As Boolean

    Set colors = ActiveSheet.Range("D19:CV68")

            found = VBA.IsNull(colors.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)
            
            colors = IIf(found, "1", " ")
End Sub
```

This gets me very close to what I need but instead of placing the 1 in just the colored cells it places the one in every cell in the range.
I'm sure there is a very basic way to do this that I am just not aware of.
I appreciate any help that I can get.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to loop here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through each cell in the range testing for no color.

```
    Dim colors As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set colors = Range("D19:CV68")
    
    For Each cell In colors
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then
            cell.Value = ""
        Else
            cell.Value = 1
        End If
    Next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

### Fill Colored Cells of a Range

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Sub FillColored()
    
    Const rgAddress As String = "D19:CV68"
    Const nStr As String = ""
    Const yStr As String = "1"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(rgAddress)
    
    Dim yrg As Range
    Dim nrg As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    
    For Each cel In rg.Cells
        If cel.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
            If nrg Is Nothing Then Set nrg = cel Else Set nrg = Union(nrg, cel)
        Else
            If yrg Is Nothing Then Set yrg = cel Else Set yrg = Union(yrg, cel)
        End If
    Next cel
    
    If Not nrg Is Nothing Then nrg.Value = nStr
    If Not yrg Is Nothing Then yrg.Value = yStr

End Sub
```